# How to load a view inside a navigation controller using xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, segue, xib

I'm trying to load a viewcontroller on tap of a button which is present in the xib file.
The viewcontroller is embedded in an navigation controller.

Right now i'm doing this i.e.,inside the IBAction() method of xib button.

`[self showViewController:viewcontroller sender:self];`

The navigation takes place with all the navigation bar items but no view is getting loaded.

Can anyone help me with this...

Thanks in advance

Comment: what you are trying? Push or  present ViewController?

Comment: Remember that showViewController is only available in iOS8.

Comment: Yes i'm trying showViewController not push..

Comment: do you want to load a view or view controller?

Comment: I want to load a view controller

Answer (score 1):

Write following function in your AppDelegate.m file:

```
-(void)loadViewController:(id)viewController
{
  UINavigationController *navigationController = appDelegate.container.centerViewController;

  NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:viewController];
  navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
}
```

and write following code in IBAction() of Button:

```
- (IBAction)leftSideMenuButtonPressed:(id)sender 
{
   LoginViewController *loginController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];

   [self loadViewController:loginController];
}
```